# How to know whether a windows process(.exe) is stopped/killed forcefully by other program by referring to windows log?

Tags: .net, windows, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, antivirus

We have a `.net` **.exe**(name=FactoryBridge.exe, this is a bridge app used for communication between our standalone desktop app with `firefox web extension`) running on our users machine.
few users(in same organization) have mentioned that they get disconnect from desktop app time to time.

when investigating bridge app log, i see multiple restarts of `FactoryBridge.exe`  have happened in a very short period of time.
This is not due to any exceptions happened inside app or bridge app(FactoryBridge.exe) as per the logs we investigated.
****We suspect one of clients security apps, might have been restricting this app**.**

**We need to whether if there's a way to know  whether a process(`.exe`) is stopped/killed forcefully by a program (which is installed in clients machine like virus app) by referring to windows log or (any other logs) and get identify that programme?**

Thanks

Comment: tried Solution #3:  in https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/service-start-time/
but, t doesnt tell a .exe was killes/shutdown by which program explicitly

Comment: Maybe `GFlags` [Monitoring Silent Process Exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/registry-entries-for-silent-process-exit) can help. However, it will not (and could not) catch "*process termination that is initiated by kernel-mode code*".